# Concat the results of type() to a string in python

Tags: python, debugging, logging, types, tostring

How can I concat the results of type() ton a string in Python?

The reason I am trying to do this is for debugging purposes (on a google app engine server with no line-by-line debugging).  Here is my code:

```
logging.debug('Type is: ' + type(some_var))
```

The error I am getting is: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'PropertiedClass' objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why we take the repr instead.

```
'Type is: %r' % (type(...),)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python is strongly typed unlike other languages you might be used to (like C). `type` returns a `type` object. You need to convert it to a string:

```
logging.debug('Type is: ' + str(type(some_var)))
```

or even better:

```
logging.debug('Type is: %s' % type(some_var))
```